# Competitive Programming Python: Repeated sum of digits Error

Tags: python

Don't know It's right place to ask this or not. But I was feeling completely stuck. Couldn't find better way to solve it.

I am newbie in competitive Programming. I was solving `Repeated sum of digits problem` Here is The Question.

`Given an integer N, recursively sum digits of N until we get a single digit.`

Example:-

```
Input:
 2
 123
 9999

Output:-
 6
 9
```

Here is my code:-

```
def sum(inp):
    if type(inp) == int:
        if len(str(inp)) <= 1:
            return inp
        else:
            a = list(str(inp))
            while len(a) > 1:
                b = 0       
                for i in a:
                    b+= int(i)
                a = list(str(b))
    return b

t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,t):
    print sum(i)
```

While submitting it gave My following error:-

```
Wrong !! The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
42

Its Correct output is:
6

And Your Output is:
0
```

However When I tested my code personally using `42` It's perfectly gives me correct Output `6`.

Here is the link of question:- [Repeated sum of digits Error](http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=1398)

Comment: Isn't your function supposed to be named `digSum()`? BTW: defining functions with the same name as built in methods can cause some confusion. For example, in Python you should avoid naming things `sum`.

Comment: Now Error is change for same code `Line 17: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: How can this even be Possible??

Comment: Please post your updated code. I ran your old version and I think it worked fine.

Comment: FWIW, there's a simple non-recursive way to perform this calculation. If `n` is the input number, its [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula) is `n%9 or n and 9`

Comment: Sorry! I did an typo.After Fixing it is giving same error as earlier.

Comment: But Why My code is giving Error.

Comment: @SanatanChaudhary: Please clarify whether the `t` in your solution is same as `N` in the original question link??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not implemented the code properly. You are iterating over `i` from `0` to `t`. Why?? The methodology goes as follows:

`N = 12345`

Calculate the sum of digits(1+2+3+4+5 = 15).

Check if it is less than 10. If so, then the current sum is the answer.. If not.. follow the same procedure by setting `N = 15`

Here is the code:

```
def sum(inp):
    while inp > 9:
        num = inp
        s = 0
        while num > 0:
            s = s + num%10
            num = num/10
        inp = s

    return inp

t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(raw_input())
    print sum(n)
```

**Edit**: I think you are iterating till `t` because you have considered `t` to be the number of testcases. So, inside the `for` loop, you should take another input for `N` for each of the testcase. [This is based on the `input` and  `output` that you have provided in the question]

**Edit-2**: I have changed the code a bit. The question asks us to find the repeated sum of `t` numbers. For that, I have added a loop where we input a number `n` corresponding to each testcase and find its repeated sum.

Comment: Actually, This is my first question. So I am having some difficulty to understand test cases `t` and `n`. It will be really helpful if you can explain it further. Thanks!

Comment: The question in the provided link says, that they will provide a number as `N` as the input and you have to find the repeated sum of digits of `N`. According to your solution, you take the input and store it in `t`[No problem]. Then you iterate from `0` to `t` and find the repeated sum of all numbers from `0` to `t`. In my solution, I find the repeated sum of only `t`. Hope you got it. There are questions where they would give `t` and for each `t` they will provide a number `N` to find the repeated sum for. But this is not the case with your question

Comment: `Your output is producing less number of lines than Expected.!!!
Maybe You are missing new line character.`

Comment: @SanatanChaudhary: Try out the code now. Made an edit (Edit2).

Comment: thanks a lot it works but didn't understand why we have to make testcases this way.